# Issue using Buttons instead of default navigation with Glide.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with the `glide.js` library to make an image slider on my website. I would like to have three pre made buttons to act as the slider buttons instead of the default navigation. The default nav seems to be using `<a>` tags.

Looking through the `js` file It seems the default navigation is created here:

```
Glide.prototype.navigation = function() {

        this.navigation.items = {};

        //CLASS
        // Navigation wrapper 
        this.navigation.wrapper = $('<div />', {
            'class': this.options.navigationClass
        }).appendTo(
            /**
             * Setting append target
             * If option is true set default target, that is slider wrapper
             * Else get target set in options
             * @type {Bool or String}
             */
            (this.options.navigation === true) ? this.parent : this.options.navigation
        );

        //Navigation controls
        for (var i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
            this.navigation.items[i] = $('<li />', {
                'href': '#',
                'class': this.options.navigationItemClass,
                // Direction and distance -> Item index forward
                'data-distance': i
            }).appendTo(this.navigation.wrapper);
        }

        // Add navCurrentItemClass to the first navigation item
        this.navigation.items[0].addClass(this.options.navigationCurrentItemClass);

        // If centered option is true
        if (this.options.navigationCenter) {
            // Center bullet navigation
            this.navigation.wrapper.css({
                'left': '50%',
                'width': this.navigation.wrapper.children().outerWidth(true) * this.navigation.wrapper.children().length,
                'margin-left': -(this.navigation.wrapper.outerWidth(true)/2)
            });
        }

    };
```

I adjusted the code, I replaced the loop with the code below to use 3 buttons I placed on my `html` page but it has no effect. I'm just wondering if I am doing something wrong, or if it is even possible? This is the changes I made to the code:

```
this.navigation.items[0] = $('.b1', {
                'href': '#',
                'class': this.options.navigationItemClass,
                'data-distance': 0
            }).appendTo(this.navigation.wrapper);

            this.navigation.items[1] = $('.b2', {
                'href': '#',
                'class': this.options.navigationItemClass,
                'data-distance': 1
            }).appendTo(this.navigation.wrapper);

            this.navigation.items[2] = $('.b3', {
                'href': '#',
                'class': this.options.navigationItemClass,
                'data-distance': 2
            }).appendTo(this.navigation.wrapper);
```

Does anyone have any idea how I might implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue. Might be helpful to anyone trying to do the same thing. It was very easy, I don't know how I didn't figure it out initially.

Basically initialize the slider as follows:

```
$('.slider').glide({
    autoplay: 5000,
    arrows: 'none',
    navigation: 'none'
});
```

Get an instance of the API:

```
var glide = $('.slider').glide().data('api_glide');
```

Then get references to each button and code the required action you want to execute when the button is clicked:

```
$('.b1').click(function(){
   console.log("Button 1 Clicked"); 
   glide.jump(1, console.log('1'));
});

$('.b2').click(function(){
   console.log("Button 2 Clicked"); 
   glide.jump(2, console.log('2'));
});

$('.b3').click(function(){
   console.log("Button 3 Clicked"); 
   glide.jump(3, console.log('3'));
});
```

All of this assumes you've got three buttons on your page like so:

```
    <button class="b1" id="b1" name="b1" >Button 1</button>
    <button class="b2" id="b2" name="b2">Button 2</button>
    <button class="b3" id="b3" name="b3">Button 3</button>
```